# How to capture all arguments after double dash (--) using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

### Background

Many command-line utilities provide special handling for all arguments after a double dash (`--`). Examples:

`git diff`: All arguments after `--` are paths (which can start with `-`):

```
git diff [options] -- [path...]
```

Some wrapper tools use this to pass arbitrary arguments on to the tool they are wrapping -- even arguments which may conflict with their own!

```
foowrap -a -- -a
             
        │     └───  Passed to wrapped tool
        └─────────  Consumed by wrapper
```

### Problem

How can we accomplish this using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an argument with `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER` to capture the rest of the arguments.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# other arguments...
parser.add_argument('remaining', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
args = parser.parse_args()
# use args.remaining...
```

`nargs='*'` can also be used, which would not include the leading `--` in the list.

Comment: `argparse.REMAINDER` is deprecated and no longer documented. It would be nice not to have to manually remove the leading `--` though.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart You can use `nargs='*'` for that (as mentioned at the end of this answer).

Comment: My memory is that the handling of '--' and `REMAINDER` has changed with releases.  I don't think `REMAINDER` is actually depricated, but it is now 'undocumentated' (i.e. most references removed from the docs).  There were too many rough edges to its use.  Looks like '--' behaves best with a `*` positional (last).

Comment: Both of our solutions suffer from the problem that a required positional argument after `--` is still consumed and not put in `remaining` (rather than raising an error).

Answer (score 1):

I've just stumbled across this problem. I solved it by removing the "--" arguments before argparse see's them.

```
# Extract underlying ("--") args before argparse parsing
for idx, arg in enumerate(argv):
    if arg == "--":
        wrapper_program_args = argv[:idx]
        underlying_tool_args = argv[idx + 1:]
        break
else:
    wrapper_program_args = argv
    underlying_tool_args = None

args = parser.parse_args(wrapper_program_args)
args.underlying_tool_args = underlying_tool_args
```

Optionally, if you want the help message to include the "--" option you may supply a custom formatter.

```
# Customer formatter required to print help message for "--" option.
class CustomHelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def format_help(self):
        original_help = super().format_help()
        return original_help + "  --\t\t\tArguments to pass to underlying tool. \n"

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=CustomHelpFormatter)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `argparse` (specifically [`parse_known_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) already supports this natively, although it is not clearly documented:

```py
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("-a", action="store_true")
p.add_argument("-b", action="store_true")

args, extra = p.parse_known_args()
print(f"args: {args}")
print(f"extra: {extra}")
```

```
$ python3 known.py -a -- -a -b
args: Namespace(a=True, b=False)
extra: ['--', '-a', '-b']
```

We can see that:

- The `-a` after `--` appears in `extra`
- The `-b` after `--` appears in `extra` and *does not* set `b=True` in the namespace

If you want to ignore the `--` separator, it can be filtered out:

```py
extra = [a for a in extra if a != "--"]
```

---

<sub>I actually discovered this while attempting to code up a "what doesn't work" example. Because it is not obvious to me from the documentation I decided to ask+answer anyway.</sub>

Comment: To ignore `--`, consider removing only the first instance, with something like `if extra and extra[0] == '--': extra.pop(0)`; that way the user can still pass a literal `"--"` as an argument by doing `python3 known.py -a -- --`, for example so you can pass it along to a wrapped command.